# Min/Max Heap or Priority Queue data structure in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, macos

Is there Min/Max Heap or Priority Queue like data structure provided by the system framework in Objective-C?

I can implement it myself or use a third party library, but I'm just curious if the system has already provide it like Java does.

Answer (score 1):

For priority queues: No. There is no generic standard in Cocoa, even classes as `NSOperationQueue` uses priority queues.

For min-max heaps: No. And you will never find. A min-max heap is a structure to implement a priority queue. Cocoa's APIs are never built on top of an implementation, but from the final collection. I. e. you have `NSArray` for ordered collections. There are several structures used for implementing that array. But you always get the final product `NSArray` independent of the structure used internally.

This is a design principle of Cocoa.

So, if someone (Apple, someone else, you) implements a priority queue, he likely uses min-max heaps. But you will never know, if it is implemented according to the concepts of Cocoa.

Comment: What about CFBinaryHeap? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfbinaryheap?language=objc

Comment: The Q has a Objective-C tag …